# Excel formulas working separately but not together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two separate formulas working in their individual cells, but when I combine them, I get a pop up saying 'there is something wrong with the formula'.
The 2 formulas I am trying to combine are:

```
=IF(OR(D7="ANNUAL",D7="SICK",D7="PUBLIC"),7.6)

# and

=(E8-D8)*24
```

The second formula will generate an hour value.

I have tried combining them like this:

```
=IF(OR(D7="ANNUAL",D7="SICK",D7="PUBLIC"),7.6,IF(E7-D7)*24)
```

Comment: Define combine.  Multiply together? Add together?  Concatenate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please tell us the meaning of "7.6" and "IF(E7-D7)*24)"? Is there any connection between them? Do you need `IF(OR(D7="ANNUAL",D7="SICK",D7="PUBLIC"),7.6,(E7-D7)*24)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one for you to fix.

`IF` requires at least one comma in it. Your final `IF` has none:

```
=IF((E7-D7)*24)
```

It looks like you don't even want that to be an `IF` so you can just remove those letters and it should work (`so (E7-D7)*24`). But if you DO want the `IF`, it has to be at least something like:

```
=IF((E7-D7)*24,)
```

or

```
=IF((E7-D7)*24,,)
```

(`IF` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` for either of those. But at least it would be returning something.)